# Postgresql - Postgis - how to filter content?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have imported a shapefile that consists of POINT data.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT a.name, 
       ST_Distance(ST_GeographyFromText(ST_AsText(a.geom)), 
                   ST_GeographyFromText(ST_AsText(b.geom)))/1000 AS distance 
FROM places a, places b 
WHERE b.name='Mumbai';
```

This query displays distances (in KM) of places from 'Mumbai'.

Giving the output:

```
                       name                       |     distance     
--------------------------------------------------+------------------
 Mumbai                                           |                0
 New Delhi                                        | 1159.26223973831
 Pune                                             |  117.86639722221
 Vittalpuram                                      | 1058.49956760668
 Kadapakkam                                       |  1064.4166204267
 Chellampatty                                     | 1136.24329302432
 Srirampur                                        |  205.27117214342
 Bhorvadi                                         |  213.69790081481
 Vaduj                                            |  227.66082105079
 Pushkar                                          |   853.0369297591
 Orcha                                            |  927.67801469371
 Phillaur                                         | 1369.21450470719
 Goraya                                           |  1381.0316667358
 Phagwara                                         | 1390.76210842565
 Ludhiana                                         | 1358.93226658828
 Mohali                                           | 1361.88704243237
 Morinda                                          | 1362.40782426879
 Kurali                                           | 1368.92321753998
 Rupnagar                                         | 1382.46666378301
 Moga                                             | 1335.85239784081
 Pahalgām                                         | 1689.72733587196
 Ambala                                           | 1327.24107571448
 Doraha                                           | 1351.41408180716
 Entrance of Ranjeet Avenue                       | 1351.43744476875
 Shaheed Jasdev Singh Nagar                       | 1353.19967929777
 Jagbir House                                     | 1357.58692404013
 Rania                                            | 1350.48320804851
 Pawa                                             | 1354.30374843403
 Sreenh                                           | 1347.01369530847
 Kaind                                            | 1345.76155280418
 Dharour                                          | 1352.71636605571
 TIBBA                                            | 1350.96268614694
 NAAT                                             |   1351.965780883
 Harnampura                                       | 1350.90891035291
 Nandpur                                          | 1354.12810806732
 Umadpur                                          | 1350.92919575633
 Dugri                                            | 1350.23846455405
 Dehlon intersection                              | 1341.15103218979
 Alwarpet                                         | 1029.21518660807
 Teynampet                                        | 1028.07582220005
 Gopalapuram                                      | 1028.37800837912
 Nandanam                                         | 1028.41251498301
 Raja Annamalai Puram                             | 1029.83876612634
 Abhiramapuram                                    | 1029.72834342923
 CIT Colony                                       | 1029.16938386861
 Sriperumbudur                                    | 1009.05941189302
 Poonamallee                                      | 1015.86523604896
```

Now I intend to filter out the results so as to view places where distance <= 500. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your query as a subselect:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT a.name ...) dummy
WHERE distance < 500.0;
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked as expected. However I am confused with 'dummy' keyword. Without dummy keyword, 'AS' clause is required (Which should be same as the one in subselect). So dummy keyword basically uses/replaces the pre-mentioned AS clause, right?

Comment: All you need is a name for the subquery. You can write that as either `(SELECT ...) dummy` or `(SELECT ...) AS dummy`. The name "dummy" is arbitrary; I chose the name since it is not used again anywhere in the query.